# Is there a plugin to integrate Face FX with Blender?

Tags: 3d, blender

Is there a plugin to integrate Face FX with Blender? I only see plugins for Maya, Max, SoftImage, and MotionBuilder on the Face FX website.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I haven't used FaceFX myself, but I do recall FaceFX uses Ogre for its editor/viewer ([here](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=51612) is a forum post about it), and there is an excellent Ogre exporter for Blender available [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=45922) (for versions 2.4.x I believe). So you could export from blender into Ogre's format, then load that into FaceFX. It's not a plugin or direct integration, but I suspect that's as good as it's going to get unless the FaceFX devs decide make a plugin (maybe contact them about it?).

Answer (score 2):

you can get facefx data out to fbx format, and it looks like you might be able to find an fbx importer for blender.  that is probably your best bet.